# align a button to the right of an ion-input field

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox

I have a `button` inside an `ionic-input` field and I would like to align to the extreme right corner of the field. The basic code looks like this

```
      <p class="text-align"> text</p>

      <button class="img-button" >

         <img class="imgClass" src="url" (click)="copy()" />

      </button>

   </ion-input>
</div>
```

One solution I have used for the parent container `input-div` is :

```
   .input-div {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     align-items: right;
     }
```

Also I have used various ion-icon CSS as well, such as `item-right` and `slot="end"` inside button like this:

```
   <button item-right slot="end" class="img-button" >
```

Basically in my code there is an outer `ion-input` tag that includes both the button (invisible with a background image) and the default text that needs to be inside. I want the icon to just stick to the right corner no matter the length of the enclosed input text.

Beyond the solutions above, I have tried using `float: right` for the button, and also tried using bootstrap's class `float-right` for it as well as other alignment solutions that I found but I am very new to CSS's alignment's features, and its not very obvious why these solutions are not working. Also when I say not working it just means that the input button/icon stays to the middle of the input field and not the extreme corner, would be great if anyone could help with this problem.

Comment: you missed a double quote in the `<img>` tag.

Comment: thanks I have corrected that, but that was just a placeholder url in the OP, it is not an error in the original code

Comment: you should use ion-item and ionic button with slot="end" attribute. 
It will be better if you create stackblitz with your current code.

Comment: I have tried those too, have added that in my original post now. Will add a basic stackblitz, my original code has a lot more complexity to the button.

Comment: what version f ionic are you using??

Comment: ionic 6.0.7 with angular 13

Comment: `<ion-item>
    <ion-input></ion-input>
    <ion-button slot="end">Click</ion-button>
</ion-item>`

Comment: have tried this as well, its not working!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way:

```
.input-div > ion-input {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.img-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Let me know in case of any other issue :)

Comment: thanks for the answer!! this just moves the button onto the second line of the input, and not to the extreme left

Comment: can you share a code snippet Or output screenshot?